# How to develop and package with ActivePython?

Tags: packaging, activepython, pypm

I have been developing (a somewhat complicated) app on core python (2.6) and have also managed to use pyinstaller to create an executable for deployment in measurements, or distribution to my colleagues. I work on the Ubuntu OS.

What has troubled me is in upgrading the versions of numpy or scipy. Some features I need are in 0.9 and I'm still on 0.7. The process of upgrading them, or matplotlib, for that matter are not elegant. The way I've upgraded on my local machine was to delete the folders of these libraries, and then manually install the newer versions.

However, this does not work for machines where I do not have root access. While trying to find a workaround, I found ActivePython. I gave it a quick try and it seems to use PyPM to download the newest scipy and numpy to its custom install location. Excellent! I don't need root access and can use the latest version of the libraries.

QUESTION:

1. If there are libraries not available on the PyPM index with ActivePython, how can I directly use the source code of those libraries (example wxpython) to include into this installation?
2. How can I use pyinstaller to build an executable using only the libraries in the ActivePython installation?